# How to align label for be on the left when using asp.net mvc(View)?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have this form below, what i want to align my label for be on the left and then texbox on the right. How do i do this on my view? Do i need to use class on my bootstrap?

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **form-inline** class on parent element or you can use **horizontal-form** of bootstrap.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#horizontal-form

Comment: Thanks so much Mehul its doing what i am expecting it.playing around with it. Bootstrap got very good class for form.